# using join method on a value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I tried to `join` and add line break to my nested array using `join` and `\n` as you can see:

```
const exampleArray = [["Hello"], ["world"], ["example"]]
    .map((el) => el)
    .join("\n");
```

everything works. I get this output which is what I want:

```
Hello

world

example
```

but when I tried to add this `exampleArray` to a value inside of an object, it shows the `\n` itself instead of line break.

this is what I did:

```
const theObj = {
    value: exampleArray,
  };
```

and this is what I get in the output:

```
Object { value: "Hello\nworld\nexample" }
```

I want to have my text with line breaks in `value`. what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: There are line breaks there. `theObj.value` and `exampleArray` are identical.

Comment: why don't you use theObj.value?

Comment: ok I found out. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is you are using objects where the data is stored in form of `{key : string}` and `{value : <number | string | boolean >}` form. You can not possibly store visual line-breaks in object-values. But if you print Object.value rather than Object itself it will print data in visual line breaks.

```js
const obj = {
  value : 'Hindi\nEnglish\nFrance'
}
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.value);


/* first one will give o/p - {
  "value": "Hindi\nEnglish\nFrance"
} */

/* second one will give o/p 
Hindi
English
France */
```

Answer (score 1):

You have text with line breaks in value. If you print in console theObj.value you will see expected.